# MongoDB returns no results in python

Tags: python, mongodb

Why does mongodb return results in shell but not in python.

Shell:

```
> db.posts.find({ Body: /html/ }).count()
5524
```

Python code:

```
query = {"Body": '/html/'}
r = mo_db.posts.find(query)
print r.count()
> 0
```

All other queries work fine, just find() works fine. Is there another way to handle slashes?!
I also tested r'/html/' and u'/html/'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying for the value as a string, not an actual regular expression object. The /.../ syntax is javascript syntax sugar for constructing the regex, but in python you need to do it with the `re` module.

Try this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("html")
query = {"Body": pattern}
r = mo_db.posts.find(query)
print r.count()
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks man. I thought the /.../ was handled by mongo.